# Python3 - print a string from a list, seperated by commas with an 'and' before the last item in a list

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm looking for a simpler (not neccessarily more pythonic or better) way of printing out a list of items in Python3, with each item seperated by a comma, except for the last item that would use an 'and'.

So far I have

```
items=['foo','bar','baz']
print(','.join(items[0:-1]),'and',items[-1])
```

However, I want to use this as part of a resource for students aged 12-13, and it's not exactly the most readable code.

edit: removed list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a little easier to read:

```
items=['foo','bar','baz']

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    if i == len(items) - 1:
        print('and ' + item)
    else:
        print(item + ',',end=' ')

>>> foo, bar, and baz
```

Updated for Python3, and I also came up with this (very similar):

```
items=['foo', 'tri', 'baz']

s = ''
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    if i == len(items) - 1:
        s += 'and {}'
    else:
        s += '{}, '

print(s.format(*items))
```

Comment: I like the look of this. They haven't covered `enumerate` yet but I can certainly introduce it. The sneaky comma on the final `print` might throw a few of them, but it's better than assembling an entire string.

Comment: There's also a good bug to fix here for lists with less than 3 elements.

Comment: Last line will have to read `print(item + ',',end=' ')` in python 3 on reflection.

Comment: @MarcScott Updated... sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `format` method:

```
 print("{} and {}".format(",".join(items[:-1]), items[-1]))
```

The first `{}` will be filled with the `join` of all the element but the last one and then you just print the last element.

Comment: Okay, and try that for `items` with a single item

Comment: @JonClements good point! It would require more testing around the list. @MarcScott I think creating each part separately would be more explicit and simple to understand. `with_coma = ",".join(items[::-1])` and assembling the whole on an other line `ouput = with_coma + " and " + items[:-1]`

Comment: @MarcScott when it comes to education it depends what aspects of programming/the language you want to show them.

Comment: @JonClements @bvidal There already going to use conditionals to get around lists of length 0,1 or 2. I think seperating out onto seperate lines would certainly help. They'll still be confused by the `join` though. Having said that, I don't want to be launching into any length `for` loops, so maybe it's best to use `join`

Comment: @MarcScott I'd use a `for` loop over using `slicing` within a `join` - going through a list can be grasped easily compared to accessing an item in a list with a negative index.

Answer (score 2):

Just break it out and comment it - it can be an exercise to do it in more advanced ways, eg:

```
if not items:
    print('')
elif len(items) == 1:
    print(items[0])
elif len(items) == 2:
    print(' and '.join(items)) # or to show `print` options
    # print(*items, sep=' and ')
else:
    words, last_word = items[:-1], items[-1]
    print(', '.join(words), 'and', last_word)
```

Using Py3.x's extending unpacking, you can make the last one be:

```
else:
    *words, last_word = items
    print(', '.join(words), 'and', last_word)
```

Alternatively, just force the `', '.join` on the lot, and split on the last `', '`, then depending if you had a separator, print appropriately.

```
words, sep, last = ', '.join(items).rpartition(', ')
if sep:
    print(words, 'and', last)
else:
    print(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your list contains at least 2 strings:

`print(','.join(items[:-1]) + ' and ' + items[-1])`

I think it will be clear enough for that ages